# How to compile this file succesfully?

Tags: llvm

I am trying to compile bt from NPB. I am getting the attached error[Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVhNA.png) . I have also attached the make file I am using.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

MakeFile:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
BENCHMARK=bt
BENCHMARKU=BT

include ../config/make.def


OBJS =  bt.o \
    ${COMMON}/c_print_results.o ${COMMON}/c_timers.o ${COMMON}/c_wtime.o

include ../sys/make.common

# npbparams.h is included by header.h
# The following rule should do the trick but many make programs (not gmake)
# will do the wrong thing and rebuild the world every time (because the
# mod time on header.h is not changed. One solution would be to 
# touch header.h but this might cause confusion if someone has
# accidentally deleted it. Instead, make the dependency on npbparams.h
# explicit in all the lines below (even though dependence is indirect). 

# header.h: npbparams.h

${PROGRAM}: config ${OBJS}
    ${CLINK} ${CLINKFLAGS} -o ${PROGRAM} ${OBJS} ${C_LIB}

.c.o:
    ${CCOMPILE} $<


bt.o:             bt.c  header.h npbparams.h

clean:
    - rm -f *.o *~ mputil*
    - rm -f npbparams.h core
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems missing `../sys/setparams`

Which should be an executable file, and takes `bt A` as input arguments.

It might be a depended tool should be built at first. I've tried a search on github, and could find some projects containing, `../sys/setparams.c`, maybe, these are what you need.

Hope it helps you.